# Wagtail Redirects created in the admin do not work on servers with wsgi

Tags: wagtail

I have 2 servers, a development server and production server, that is running a wagtail blog with some static react pages.  When running python manage.py runserver locally, redirects that are added in the wagtail admin work fine, but they do not work on the apache/mod_wsgi setup.  I have also set it up with nginx and wsgi, but the same issue occurs.  I am not sure what settings I am missing on wsgi, apache, or nginx that is preventing wagtail from being able to redirect.

I have dug through every forum I can find and gone through django setup on apache and uwsgi and i have no idea what to look for or try.

Answer (score 0):

The setting that enables redirects is the line

```
'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
```

in the MIDDLEWARE setting. (You'll also need `'wagtail.contrib.redirects'` in INSTALLED_APPS, but if that wasn't there you wouldn't see the Redirects option in the Wagtail admin either, so that's not the issue.)

There's nothing in the server-level configuration (i.e. outside of Django) that would affect the behaviour of redirects, so given that it's working on runserver but not the 'real' webservers, I'd suspect this is a discrepancy between the development.py and production.py settings files.

Other things to double-check:

- Redirects are only triggered when nothing else matches the given URL (i.e. without the redirect in place, it would be a 404 Not Found error). If your production site has a page at that URL, the redirect won't work;
- If the redirect is set up to happen on a specific site (rather than the "From site:" option being left as "all sites"), then make sure your site records under Settings -> Sites match the real hostnames you're using in production.